# Firebase Firestore Data Not Visible Issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.forms

I ran into issue where Firestore is not reflecting data on client.
Lets say when I create cart manually from Firebase Console it reflects on client side but when I create Cart from client side it does not reflects, although a empty card appears but its null. Assist me on this

*Firestore Rules are Public*

*Data Calling Method*

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<T>> GetCollection(string collection)
   {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<T>>();
            await DataStore.Collection(collection).Get()
                    .AddOnCompleteListener(new OnCollectionCompleteListener<T>(tcs));
            return await tcs.Task;
   }
```

*Thanks*

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on my own. While working with Firestore, I understood that if you keep any field null in Firestore, the data inside the document will not be visible. So make sure to not leave any field empty.